# Setting a timer to a specific code

Tags: javascript, timer

Setting a timer using this code. I have no idea how to do it.

Can someone show me how to do it please.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure

```
 // Start with one mark.
    performance.mark("mySetTimeout-start");

    // Wait some time.
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Mark the end of the time.
      performance.mark("mySetTimeout-end");

      // Measure between the two different markers.
      performance.measure(
        "mySetTimeout",
        "mySetTimeout-start",
        "mySetTimeout-end"
      );

      // Get all of the measures out.
      // In this case there is only one.
      var measures = performance.getEntriesByName("mySetTimeout");
      var measure = measures[0];
      console.log("setTimeout milliseconds:", measure.duration)

      // Clean up the stored markers.
      performance.clearMarks();
      performance.clearMeasures();
    }, 1000);
```

I want to set a timer to this

**As an example:**

```
  <img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxOCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEyMjYgMTQ4MSI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTAgMTM5NFY4N0MwIDQ2LjMgMTMuMyAxOS44IDQwIDcuNSA2Ni43LTQuOCA5OC43LjMgMTM2IDIzbDEwMzQgNjM0YzM3LjMgMjIuNyA1NiA1MC4zIDU2IDgzcy0xOC43IDYwLjMtNTYgODNMMTM2IDE0NThjLTM3LjMgMjIuNy02OS4zIDI3LjgtOTYgMTUuNS0yNi43LTEyLjMtNDAtMzguOC00MC03OS41eiIgZmlsbD0iIzAwNTlkZCIvPgogPC9zdmc+'>
```

Comment: The JS code runs fine. Its not clear to me what you want to do, and how it relates to the <img> tag. Can you explain?

Comment: Set a timer to it so I can view the milliseconds it takes to load. That's basically it. How would I set that up. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onClick() {

  // Start with one mark.
  performance.mark("mySetTimeout-start");

  // Wait some time.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Mark the end of the time.
    performance.mark("mySetTimeout-end");

    // Measure between the two different markers.
    performance.measure(
      "mySetTimeout",
      "mySetTimeout-start",
      "mySetTimeout-end"
    );

    // Get all of the measures out.
    // In this case there is only one.
    var measures = performance.getEntriesByName("mySetTimeout");
    var measure = measures[0];

    // Clean up the stored markers.
    performance.clearMarks();
    performance.clearMeasures();
    
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = measure.duration
  }, 1000)
}

document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
  <img id='play' src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxOCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEyMjYgMTQ4MSI+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTAgMTM5NFY4N0MwIDQ2LjMgMTMuMyAxOS44IDQwIDcuNSA2Ni43LTQuOCA5OC43LjMgMTM2IDIzbDEwMzQgNjM0YzM3LjMgMjIuNyA1NiA1MC4zIDU2IDgzcy0xOC43IDYwLjMtNTYgODNMMTM2IDE0NThjLTM3LjMgMjIuNy02OS4zIDI3LjgtOTYgMTUuNS0yNi43LTEyLjMtNDAtMzguOC00MC03OS41eiIgZmlsbD0iIzAwNTlkZCIvPgogPC9zdmc+'>
<div id='time'></div>
```